# Flutter BloC migration from old version to 8.0

Tags: android, flutter, bloc

I'm trying to make a flutter app from a guide, to an updated version with newer BloC version but, i've trouble with the changes from the old version to the new version...

First, here is the error i got when i try to press "play" on my application at this stage:

> Bad state: add(PlayerEvent) was called without a registered event handler.
> Make sure to register a handler via on((event, emit) {...})

For what i can understand, this is because mapEventToState is deprecated and from BloC 8.0.1, i've tried to make the change by myself but, i'm a beginner and i've trouble understanding how i should do it.

Here is my actual code who is now deprecated

```java
class PlayBloc extends Bloc<PlayEvent, PlayState>{

  final PlayerControl radioPlayer;


  PlayBloc({required this.radioPlayer}) : assert(radioPlayer != null),super(isPausedState());

   @override //Déprécié
  PlayState get initialState => isPausedState();
 
  @override
  Stream<PlayState> mapEventToState(PlayEvent event) async* {
    if(event is PlayerEvent){
      yield isPlayingState();
      await radioPlayer.play(url: event.url);
    }
    else if(event is StopEvent){
      yield isPausedState();
      await radioPlayer.stop();
    }
  }
  
}
```

could explain to me how to transform this? I tried following the solution proposed here:
[Flutter bloc migration due to mapEventToState is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549430/flutter-bloc-migration-due-to-mapeventtostate-is-not-working)

but I have trouble understanding the changes that have been made..

Thank You

**EDIT :** Tried again to change it into BloC 8.0 standard, still no luck, it throws an error on "on(**mapEventToState**)"

> The argument type 'Future Function(PlayerEvent)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr Function(PlayerEvent, Emitter)'. (Documentation)

```java
PlayBloc({required this.radioPlayer}) : assert(radioPlayer != null),super(isPausedState()){
    on<PlayerEvent>(mapEventToState);
  }

  //@override //Déprécié
  //PlayState get initialState => isPausedState();
  Future<void> mapEventToState (
      PlayerEvent event
      ) async {
    if (event is PlayerEvent) {
      if (state is isPausedState) {
        await radioPlayer.play(url: event.url);
        emit(isPlayingState());
      } else if (state is isPlayingState) {
        await radioPlayer.stop();
        emit(isPausedState());
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What the error suggests is that you need to register an `on(Event, Emitter)` added to the constructor of your Bloc. The first step I would take is to migrate to a single function. This is what I would do:

1. Add `bloc_concurrency` to `pubspec.yml`: This is important so that your new `on(Event, Emitter)` behaves exactly like your `mapEventToState`.
2. Change `PlayBloc` to something like this:

```dart
class PlayBloc extends Bloc<PlayerEvent, PlayerState> {
  PlayBloc({required this.radioPlayer}) : assert(radioPlayer != null),super(isPausedState()){
    on<PlayerEvent>(
      mapEventToState,
      transformer: sequential(),
    );
  }

  //@override //Déprécié
  //PlayState get initialState => isPausedState();
  Future<void> mapEventToState (
      PlayerEvent event,
      Emitter<MyState> emit,
      ) async {
    if (event is PlayerEvent) {
      if (state is isPausedState) {
        await radioPlayer.play(url: event.url);
        emit(isPlayingState());
      } else if (state is isPlayingState) {
        await radioPlayer.stop();
        emit(isPausedState());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that `mapEventToState` now receives both the `event` and the `emit`. This last emitter is the function you will use to update the state of your Bloc.

For reference, here are a couple of posts by VeryGoodVentures about [Bloc's new API](https://verygood.ventures/blog/whats-new-in-bloc-v7-2-0) and [how to use concurrency](https://verygood.ventures/blog/how-to-use-bloc-with-streams-and-concurrency). And then (shameless plug), here's a [tutorial about Bloc 8.0 I wrote a while back](https://www.raywenderlich.com/32962047-bloc-8-0-tutorial-for-flutter-getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code. In latest version to update changes in UI from bloc you have to write emit instead of yeild and async instead of async*.

New method call like this

```
on((event, emit) async{
      
});
```

You can also call like this

```
on<className>((event, emit) async{
          
});
```

For reference I shared you one my bloc close.

```
class CovidBloc extends Bloc<CovidEvent, CovidState> {
  CovidBloc() : super(CovidInitial()) {
    final ApiRepository _apiRepository = ApiRepository();

    on<GetCovidList>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        print("Event2: $event");
        emit(CovidLoading());
        final mList = await _apiRepository.fetchCovidList();
        emit(CovidLoaded(mList));
        if (mList.error != null) {
          emit(CovidError(mList.error));
        }
      } on NetworkError {
        emit(const CovidError("Failed to fetch data. is your device online?"));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i've tried it, if i use async  instead of async* it throws me :

Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'. (Documentation)  Try fixing the return type of the function, or removing the modifier 'async' from the function body.

if i use async * then it's fine but it still doesn't work unfortunatly, same error, i edited my first posts with some change regarding bloc 8.0.0 but still not luck either :/

Comment: Yes now you have to listen this emit state in UI code using builder listener block.

Comment: You mean, on the "OnPressed" ? at this time it's like this :
`context.read<PlayBloc>().add(PlayerEvent(url: _FunUrl));`

Comment: Yes it's event execution code.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure to understand what i'have to do ? :/

Comment: Check my answer. I update it with example