# How to emit multiple states inside an async Bloc event handler

Tags: flutter-bloc

Somewhere in a widget using `BlocConsumer`. Adding hints that we are uploading a file to a REST API.

```
var file = File(pickedFileList[0].path);
var fileAsBinary = await file.openRead().toList();
var data = fileAsBinary.expand((element) => element).toList();
var lengthSync = file.lengthSync();
var name = file.uri.pathSegments.last;
// Raise Bloc event
bloc.add(PhotoAdded(photoKey: name, data: data, lengthSync: lengthSync));
```

Bloc:

```
// Event handler registration
on<PhotoAdded>((event, emit) async => await _handlePhotoAdded(emit, event));

// Event handler
_handlePhotoAdded(Emitter<PhotoAddedUploadingState> emit,
      PhotoAdded event) async {
    // We use the repository pattern
    await repository.addPhoto(event.photoKey, event.data, event.lengthSync, (sentBytes, totalBytes) { 
      double progressPercent = sentBytes / totalBytes;// * 100;
      emit(PhotoUploadingState(progress: progressPercent));

    });
  }
```

Repository (for demonstration purposes we're mocking raising twice the onSendProgress callback):

```
Future<void> addPhoto(
      String photoKey,
      List<int> fileAsBinary,
      int lengthSync,
      void Function(int sentBytes, int totalBytes)? onSendProgress) async {

    onSendProgress!(1, 5);
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      onSendProgress(1, 2);
    });

  }
```

In the first `onSendProgress` invocation the state works and shows my widget with the progress bar, in the second where the state with the progress bar value will change throws the below exception. I get the exception, we are trying to update the state again while we already emitted a state to the widget but new to this I am not sure how to proceed to accomplish what I want.

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:bloc/src/emitter.dart': Failed assertion: line 114 pos 7: '!_isCompleted':
emitter.dart:114
emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers
and use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
ensure the event handler has not completed.
  **BAD**
  on<Event>((event, emit) {
    future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
  });
  **GOOD**
  on<Event>((event, emit) async {
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      _Emitter.call
emitter.dart:114
#3      TheBloc._handlePhotoAdded.<anonymous closure>
the_bloc.dart:826
#4      Pr<…>
Application finished.
```

I thought of using the Bloc listener but as far as I know it's not for rebuilding widgets but for navigation, modal presentations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after doing some aggressive Googling I ended up trying the below signature for registering an event handler and it just worked.

```
FutureOr<void> _handlePhotoAdded(PhotoAdded event, Emitter< PhotoAddedUploadingState> emit)
{
  // ...
}
```

It seems that based on the event handler method signature Bloc will manage it differently under the hood...kind of making sense though. This Dart is giving me some headache sometimes but overall cool.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to how you are handling async code. Your event handler `_handlePhotoAdded` is marked as async and awaits `addPhoto`.
In this method you execute `onSendProgress` synchronously, and then start a delayed task. Crucially you are *not* returning this future and thus `_handlePhotoAdded` finishes it's execution and `Bloc` is probably closing the emitter stream in the background. The error message is actually quite helpful & correct here:

> emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
> This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
> Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers
> and use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
> ensure the event handler has not completed.

One way of fixing this would be to return the `Future` which is created by the `Future.delayed` constructor:

```
Future<void> addPhoto(
      String photoKey,
      List<int> fileAsBinary,
      int lengthSync,
      void Function(int sentBytes, int totalBytes)? onSendProgress) async {

    onSendProgress!(1, 5);
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      onSendProgress(1, 2);
    });
  }
```

Comment: These are great information. Thanks.